# I have different excel files in the same folder

Tags: python, dataframe, file

I have different excel files in the same folder, in each of them there are the same sheets. I need to select the last sheet of each file and join them all by the columns (that is, form a single table). The columns of all files are named the same. I think it is to identify the dataframe of each file and then paste them. But I do not know how

Comment: You should at least post an attempt you made. You're asking to solve a whole problem, stack overflow is more for solving specific issues with your code. As a tip though, you might find it easier if you read the excel files using pandas `read_excel`, then save the last sheet from each file to a csv file and work off that.

Comment: I know how to do it, but for few files. I would like to know if there is a way to read many files and carry out the process described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what Recessive said and use a for loop to read the excel file one by one and do the following:

> excel_files = os.listdir(filepath)

> for file in excel_files:
>
> > read excel file sheet

> > save specific column to variable

> > end of loop

> concatenate each column from different variables to one dataframe